# Multi-functionality facebook app design: one big app vs. breaking into smaller apps?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

Okay, I am developing a Facebook app that has multiple sections, each of which serve as a single page that does a simple task for the user, and requires different set of permissions to accomplish that task.

My question is: should I create **multiple apps**, one for each of the sections? or do I create a **single app**, and request new permissions when the user goes from one section to another?

Comment: Why don't you create a single app with all permissions at once?

Comment: Because the user would find it really strange and fishy that an app page asks for your and your friends' locations, posts, likes, groups, birthdays... and loads of other permissions, to achieve a simple task such as showing a graph representing your friends' age distribution, for example.

Comment: Besides, I am interested to know about any implications on average users' expectations and experience when it comes to this, would the user feel it strange to pack all functionality in one app? are there any concerns and implications I should take into account..

Comment: I see.. 
I suggest you go with single app with extra permissions per section, because multiple apps would look more fishy for the user.

Answer (score 3):

Although I think this question is more appropriate for [Stack UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com), I'll answer it here.

If these tasks/sections are not at all relevant to each other, and the user will not likely need to use another task if s(he) used one. Then it might be good idea to make every section a separate app. Even it you will ask on permissions separately, it's still hard to promote an app which has no specific "topic", and it's not nice to show the user things that are not really interesting to him.

However, if these tasks are interconnected, i.e, the user will most likely need to use many of them once (s)he starts using one, then you should have a single app. This opinion is based on many reasons:

- It's a bad experience to ask the user to authenticate a completely different app if he (for example) clicked on a button in the current app.
- Separation will make your apps less popular, it's more attracting to see a single app that has 100,000 users than see 10 apps that have 10,000 each. Besides, promoting and spreading a single app is easier. In fact, for this reason I would even choose to make it a single app even if the sections are not relevant to each other.

As for how to ask for permissions in a single app, this is dependent on many factors including:

- **The target audience:** if your target users are lazy and don't really care about what permissions they are giving, then it'll be a good idea to ask for all permissions at the very beginning, this is easier for development and less interrupting for the user.
- **The variation of permissions:** if sections request so different permissions, like having a section that only require light read permissions, and another that require page management permission; then it's better to ask for additional permissions every time the user starts using a "more dangerous" section. On the other hand, if most sections require similar permissions, like having all the sections require read permissions only, then it's probably better not to interrupt the user every time he enters a new section.